# UIButton hidden but working

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting

I am doing an application , using ARC. I add a button to the navigation controller as a subview and then remove it. It works fine on simulator but on device, after using for a long time, the buttons are hidden , but on touching on that area, it responds.

Could it be some memory issue?

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you place `button.hidden = YES`, also place `button.enabled = NO`.

Comment: Well, in his question he says "I add the buton ... as a subview and then remove it." so I don't think that he's actually "hiding" it using the hidden method....